# Project center of camera to coordinates in charuco board

Tags: python, opencv, camera, aruco

I am detecting the corners of a charuco Board with the standard board detector, which all works really well.

What Id like to do is to get the x and y with respect to the Charuco board axes and display it in a "virtual view". Currently I am using the rvecs and tvecs of a solvePnP with the IPPE method (it requires more than 6 points), but when I display it in the virtual view I alway have a lot of noise comming from the fact that due to inconsistent lighting, markers fade in and out of detection, with messes with the solvePnP algorithm.

I think using the crosshair would be a better way of determining x and y for this case

Does anyone has experience with this? Thanks in advance

example of what I would want:

[image: 1]

I tried using SolvePnP and it got inconsistencies and noise coming from the lighting